# How to execute MYSQL REPLACE to replace multiple or single space with | (pipe)

Tags: mysql, c, regex

```
SELECT * FROM `spamfilter` WHERE `words` REGEXP (REPLACE('test won hello spam', " ", "|"))
```

works for one space.

```
SELECT * FROM `spamfilter` WHERE `words` REGEXP (REPLACE('test[2 spaces]won[2 spaces]hello[2 spaces]spam', "[2 spaces]", "|"))
```

works for two spaces.

```
SELECT * FROM `spamfilter` WHERE `words` REGEXP (REPLACE('test[5 space]won[2 space]hello[1 space]spam', " ", "|"))
```

won't work for multiple or single spaces in one query.

This works with one space and I need it to work if it has multiple spaces in one query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know the maximum length of multi spacers in the text.

Let's say maximum length is 3: in this case you have to run the query 3 times like this:

```
// for three spaces
 update tableName set colName = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(colName)), '   ', '|') where colName like '% %'

//for two spaces
 update tableName set colName = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(colName)), '  ', '|') where colName like '% %'

//for one space
update tableName set colName = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(colName)), ' ', ' ') where colName like '% %'
```

There may be a better approach, but this one should work too..

Answer (score 0):

I think this handles up to 12 spaces:

```
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(TRIM(col), '     ', ' ')  --5
                   '   ', ' ')    --3
                   '  ', ' ')     --2
                   ' ', '|')
```